# Mapper already initialized

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I have a 3-layer architecture Web Api solution with 3 projects inside: data, business and presentation layers. I need to initialize two different mappers in two business and presentation layers.

I've created a static class and method to initialize one mapper in business logic:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Shop.BLL.DTOModels;
using Shop.DAL.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Shop.BLL.InitMapper
{
    public static class InitializeMapperBLL
    {
        public static void RegisterMappings()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Category, DTOCategoryModel>());
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Shop.DAL.Repositories;
using AutoMapper;
using Shop.BLL.DTOModels;
using Shop.DAL.Models;
using Shop.BLL.Interfaces;
using Shop.DAL.Interfaces;
using Shop.BLL.InitMapper;

namespace Shop.BLL.Services
{
    public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
    {
        IUnitOfWork Database { get; set; }

        public CategoryService(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            Database = uow;
        }

        public IEnumerable<DTOCategoryModel> GetCategories()
        {
//I call it here
            InitializeMapperBLL.RegisterMappings();

            return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Category>, List<DTOCategoryModel>>(Database.Categories.GetAll());
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Database.Dispose();
        }


    }
}
```

And in the presentation layer I do the same thing:

```
using AutoMapper;
using Shop.API.ViewModels;
using Shop.BLL.DTOModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Shop.API.MapperInit
{
    public static class InitializeMapperAPI
    {
        public static void RegisterMappings()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<DTOCategoryModel, CategoryViewModel>());
        }
    }
}
```

And call in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
      //here I call it
            InitializeMapperAPI.RegisterMappings();

            CreateKernel();
        }
```

And I've got the error Mapper already initialized. You must call Initialize once per application domain/process.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you need someway to inject same mapper object in both layers and add new mappings instead of initializing it for every layer seperately

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47241708/automapper-mapper-already-initialized-error  refer this link to solve your problem.

Comment: @Оля please have a look at this article :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1129953/ASP-MVC-with-Automapper-Profiles

Comment: @MohanSrinivas, I have seen it and wrote my code according to the first answer in that question

the problem is that I actually call Mapper.Initialize twice

Comment: @Оля that article i think would help you configure the way i suggested

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances

Comment: You can create AutoMapper Profiles for each layer. Then you can load the Profile(s) when you need to create a Mapper instance. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49312728/2030565.

Comment: hope this will help , https://stackoverflow.com/a/51780752/6602130

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is using reflection and automapper profiles. This has worked very well in projects I've used it in.

Create one automapper profile class in each of your projects/layers. Each profile class should contain only the maps that it itself needs. An example of what one of these would look like is the following:

```
  //Profile here is of type AutoMapper.Profile
  public class BusinessLayerMapperConfig : Profile
  {
    public BusinessLayerMapperConfig()
    {
      //create layer specific maps
      CreateMap<MyObjectDTO, MyObjectViewModel>();
    }

    public override string ProfileName
    {
      get { return this.GetType().ToString(); }
    }
  }
```

and then somewhere real close to the entry point of your app (I call the following method from the `ApplicationStart` method in `Global.asax.cs`), initialize all of your profiles like this:

```
public static void RegisterMaps()
    {
      //get all projects' AutoMapper profiles using reflection
      var assembliesToScan = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
      var allTypes = assembliesToScan.SelectMany(a => a.ExportedTypes).ToArray();

      var profiles =
          allTypes
              .Where(t => typeof(Profile).GetTypeInfo().IsAssignableFrom(t.GetTypeInfo()))
              .Where(t => !t.GetTypeInfo().IsAbstract);

      //add each profile to our static AutoMapper
      Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
      {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
          cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
      });
    }
```

this will allow you to separate your maps logically by the layer they are used in as well as ensure you initialize them only once.

Comment: That's [built in](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#profile-instances) now.

Comment: It's not the same. Automapper can scan assemblies for profiles for you, and you are doing that manually.