# I want to place Automapper profile in my Business Layer

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I've created a web api core 2.0 application.
I've got my main app and the Business Layer.
I want to place the automapper profile in the business layer so that all the mappings are made in the business layer. My business layer is just a class library project.

Is this possible? or do I need  to place all my mapping in a Profile class in the main app?

Just a theoretical explanation can help.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but it depends on where the model classes reside.

You can give each layer or project a `Profile` where you map the appropriate model classes. Then in the project where you want to use the mapper, create the `ObjectMapper` class to load the Profiles.

```
namespace BL.Config
{
    public class MapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public MapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Entity, Dto>();
            ...
        }
    }

    public class ObjectMapper
    {
        public static IMapper Mapper
        {
            get { return mapper.Value; }
        }

        public static IConfigurationProvider Configuration
        {
            get { return config.Value; }
        }

        public static Lazy<IMapper> mapper = new Lazy<IMapper>(() =>
        {
            var mapper = new Mapper(Configuration);
            return mapper;
        });

        public static Lazy<IConfigurationProvider> config = new Lazy<IConfigurationProvider>(() =>
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<BL.Config.MapperProfile>();
                cfg.AddProfile<AppCore.Config.MapperProfile>();  // any other profiles you need to use
            });

            return config;
        });
    }
}
```

When I need to use AutoMapper, I use the `ObjectMapper.Mapper` to get my mapper instance. I like to add this to an abstract service.

```
public interface IAutoMapperService
{
    IMapper Mapper { get; }
}

public abstract class AutoMapperService : IAutoMapperService
{
    public IMapper Mapper
    {
        get { return BAL.Config.ObjectMapper.Mapper; }
    }
}
```

And usage: The service has the Mapper member.

```
public class SomeService : AutoMapperService, ISomeService
{
    public Foo GetFoo()
    {
        var foo = Mapper.Map<Foo>(bar);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Or just implement the `IAutoMapperService` if you can't inherit another base class.

The downside is BL requires the AutoMapper dependency. But using this way I find I can hide many models from the other layers.

Comment: Saved my day, thx. Just one thing, I think you're missing `return config;` for your ObjectMapper.config. At least I had to add that in order to get it to work.

Comment: @HSBallina yes, it was missing.

Comment: @Jasen how to  implement the IAutoMapperService in controller?

Comment: @Ljt declare a `IMapper Mapper` getter property which returns your configured mapper from your `ObjectMapper` class. You can pretty much copy that from my AutoMapperService above.